# How to change the size of dots in beeswarm plots in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I've been looking at [this example](https://gf.neocities.org/co2bs/co2bee.html) of a beeswarm plot in d3.js and I'm trying to figure out how to change the size of the dots and without getting the circles to overlap. It seems if the radius of the dots change, it doesn't take this into account when running the calculations of where to place the dots.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633803/how-to-handle-collisions-in-beeswarm-plot-in-d3/42635075#42635075 may be of interest as well - related but slightly different take on this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cool visualization.

I've made a plunk of it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/VwyXfbc94oXp6kXQ7JFx?p=preview and modified it to work a bit more like you're looking for (I think).   The real key is changing the call to handle collision to vary based on the radius of the circles (in the original post it's hard coded to 4, which works well when `r === 3` but fails as r grows).  The changes:

- Make the circle radius into a variable (line 7 of script.js, `var r = 3;`)
- Change the `d3.forceCollide` call to use that radius and a multiplier - line 110 (`.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(r * 1.333))`)
- Change the `.enter()` call to use that radius as well (line 130: `.attr("r", r)`)

This works reasonably well for reasonable values of `r` - but you'll need to adjust the height, and it might even be nice to just change the whole thing so that `r` is based on `height` (e.g. `var r = height * .01`).  You'll notice that as is now, the circles go off the bottom and top of the graph area.

This post might be of interest as well: [Conflict between d3.forceCollide() and d3.forceX/Y() with high strength() value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185092/conflict-between-d3-forcecollide-and-d3-forcex-y-with-high-strength-value)

Here's the whole of `script.js` for posterity:

```
var w = 1000, h = 280;

var padding = [0, 40, 34, 40];
var r = 5;

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([ padding[3], w - padding[1] ]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(10, ".0s")
    .tickSizeOuter(0);

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["asia", "africa", "northAmerica", "europe", "southAmerica", "oceania"])
    .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#ffff33']);

d3.select("#africaColor").style("color", colors("africa"));
d3.select("#namericaColor").style("color", colors("northAmerica"));
d3.select("#samericaColor").style("color", colors("southAmerica"));
d3.select("#asiaColor").style("color", colors("asia"));
d3.select("#europeColor").style("color", colors("europe"));
d3.select("#oceaniaColor").style("color", colors("oceania"));

var formatNumber = d3.format(",");

var tt = d3.select("#svganchor").append("div")  
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("#svganchor")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var xline = svg.append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "1,2");

var chartState = {};

chartState.variable = "totalEmission";
chartState.scale = "scaleLinear";
chartState.legend = "Total emissions, in kilotonnes";

d3.csv("co2bee.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var dataSet = data;

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.totalEmission; }));

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding[2]) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    var legend = svg.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", w / 2)
        .attr("y", h - 4)
        .attr("font-family", "PT Sans")
        .attr("font-size", 12)
        .attr("fill", "darkslategray")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("class", "legend");

    redraw(chartState.variable);

    d3.selectAll(".button1").on("click", function(){
        var thisClicked = this.value;
        chartState.variable = thisClicked;
        if (thisClicked == "totalEmission"){
            chartState.legend = "Total emissions, in kilotonnes";
        }
        if (thisClicked == "emissionPerCap"){
            chartState.legend = "Per Capita emissions, in metric tons";
        }
        redraw(chartState.variable);
    });

    d3.selectAll(".button2").on("click", function(){
        var thisClicked = this.value;
        chartState.scale = thisClicked;
        redraw(chartState.variable);
    });

    d3.selectAll("input").on("change", filter);

    function redraw(variable){

        if (chartState.scale == "scaleLinear"){ xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([ padding[3], w - padding[1] ]);}

        if (chartState.scale == "scaleLog"){ xScale = d3.scaleLog().range([ padding[3], w - padding[1] ]);}

        xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataSet, function(d) { return +d[variable]; }));

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            .ticks(10, ".0s")
            .tickSizeOuter(0);

        d3.transition(svg).select(".x.axis").transition().duration(1000)
            .call(xAxis);

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(dataSet)
            .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) { return xScale(+d[variable]); }).strength(2))
            .force("y", d3.forceY((h / 2)-padding[2]/2))
            .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(r * 1.333))
            .stop();

        for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; ++i) simulation.tick();

        var countriesCircles = svg.selectAll(".countries")
            .data(dataSet, function(d) { return d.countryCode});

        countriesCircles.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", (h / 2)-padding[2]/2)
            .remove();

        countriesCircles.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "countries")
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", (h / 2)-padding[2]/2)
            .attr("r", r)
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return colors(d.continent)})
            .merge(countriesCircles)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { console.log(d); return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        legend.text(chartState.legend);

        d3.selectAll(".countries").on("mousemove", function(d) {
            tt.html("Country: <strong>" + d.countryName + "</strong><br>"
            + chartState.legend.slice(0, chartState.legend.indexOf(",")) + ": <strong>" + formatNumber(d[variable]) + "</strong>" + chartState.legend.slice(chartState.legend.lastIndexOf(" ")))
                .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 12 + 'px')
                .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 25 + 'px')
                .style("opacity", 0.9);

                xline.attr("x1", d3.select(this).attr("cx"))
                    .attr("y1", d3.select(this).attr("cy"))
                    .attr("y2", (h - padding[2]))
                    .attr("x2",  d3.select(this).attr("cx"))
                    .attr("opacity", 1);

        }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
            tt.style("opacity", 0);
            xline.attr("opacity", 0);
        });

        d3.selectAll(".x.axis, .legend").on("mousemove", function(){
            tt.html("This axis uses SI prefixes:<br>m: 10<sup>-3</sup><br>k: 10<sup>3</sup><br>M: 10<sup>6</sup>")
                .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 12 + 'px')
                .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 25 + 'px')
                .style("opacity", 0.9);
        }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
            tt.style("opacity", 0);
        });

    //end of redraw
    }

    function filter(){

        function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
          var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
          var checkboxesChecked = [];
          for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
             if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].defaultValue);
             }
          }
          return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
        }

        var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("continent");

        var newData = [];

        if (checkedBoxes == null){ 
            dataSet = newData; 
            redraw(); 
            return;
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++){
            var newArray = data.filter(function(d){
                return d.continent == checkedBoxes[i];
            });
            Array.prototype.push.apply(newData, newArray);
        }

        dataSet = newData;

        redraw(chartState.variable);

    //end of filter
    }

//end of d3.csv
});
```