# How to handle collisions in Beeswarm plot in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been playing around with this example [here](https://gf.neocities.org/co2bs/co2bee.html) for a little while. What I'm trying to do is highlight a single node/circle in the plot (by making it larger with a border; later I want to add text or a letter inside it too).

Currently, I've made the circle for `Bhutan` larger in the plot like the following:

```
.attr("r", 
    function(d){return ( d.countryName === "Bhutan" ? r + 4 : r);})
.attr("stroke", function(d){if (d.countryName==="Bhutan"){return "black"}})
```

However, it overlaps with the other circles. What would be the best approach to avoid these collisions/overlaps? Thanks in advance.

Link to Plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/rG6X07Kzkg9LeVVuL0PH?p=preview

---

I tried the following to add a letter inside the bhutan circle

```
    //find bhutan circle and add a "B" to it
    countriesCircles
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.countryName === "Bhutan"; })
    .text("B");
```

Updated Plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/Bza5AMxqUr2HW9CYdpC6?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly different problem than in this question here: [How to change the size of dots in beeswarm plots in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631671/how-to-change-the-size-of-dots-in-beeswarm-plots-in-d3-js?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You have a few options that I can think of:

- Set the `forceCollide` to be your `largest possible radius * 1.33`, e.g. `(r + 4) * 1.33`.  This will prevent overlapping, but spread things out a lot and doesn't look that great.
- Add the radius property to each entry in your array and make the collide work based off that, which will look a bit better but not perform as awesomely for large sets.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```
...
d3.csv("co2bee.csv", function(d) {
    if (d.countryName === "Bhutan") {
      d.r = r + 4;
    } else {
      d.r = r;
    }
    return d;
}, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var dataSet = data;
...
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(dataSet)
  ...
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) { return d.r * 1.33; }))
  ...

countriesCircles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "countries")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", (h / 2)-padding[2]/2)
    .attr("r",  function(d){ return d.r; })
....
```

Use the `row` function in `d3.csv` to add a property to each member of the array called `r`, and check the country name to determine which one gets the larger value.  Then use that value wherever you need to mess with the radius.

I guess it would've been possible to check the country name everywhere the radius was impacted (e.g. `.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) { return d.countryName === "Bhutan" ? (r + 4) * 1.33 : r * 1.33; })`, etc.).  This feels a bit cleaner to me, but it might be cleaner still by abstracting out the radius from the data entries themselves...

Forked your plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tet1DVvHtC7mHz91eAYW?p=preview

Comment: This is a neat solution. Thank you! On a separate note, I'm trying to add a letter to the Bhutan circle. Any pointers? I will add what I've tried to my question.

Comment: I can't really think of a good way to do that off the top of my head - might be able to play around with it later

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. However, I'm curious: why two different users asked about my code almost at the same time? A homework maybe?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I was stuck with this problem for some time, and then when I saw Dan answering a question about the very same graph. I thought it was a good time to ask lol I wish I was still in college doing homework :)